# SPSS: How to compute duration between two points of time (without full date information)

Tags: datetime, spss

In a study of mine, participants gave me the time they

1. usually go to bed (bedtime) and
2. usually get up from bed (outofbed) (format is hh:mm).

I now want to compute a new variable indicating the duration between these two points of time.

I already used SPPS' inbuilt TimeWizard and the function `newVar = CTIME.HOURS(outofbed-bedtime)`. This does not give me correct results for bedtime hours before 24.00 (since e.g. 23.00-7.00 = 16h, instead of 8h).

I thoroughly used my googlefoo skills, but all answers I found used information on both date AND Time (eg. dd:mm:hh:mm). I expect the problem is that SPSS internally saves all datetime information as seconds since the beginning of the gregorian calendar. Since I lack the information of the date, SPSS does not have absolute values with which it can calculate. At least, this is my assumption so far.

I hope you know a solution to my problem.
Cheers, Dekay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could just calculate `24 - CTIME.HOURS(bedtime - outofbed)` - which can be interpreted as calculating the awake time and then subtracting that from 24 hours.

You need to watch out for people that have different schedules though, such as those on night shift. The below logic should solve that problem, presuming those with inverted schedules always get out of bed later in the day than they go to sleep.

```
DATA LIST FREE / outofbed bedtime (2TIME5).
BEGIN DATA
08:00 22:00
06:00 21:00
05:30 20:30
21:45 07:00
END DATA.

DO IF outofbed < bedtime.
  COMPUTE sleepDur = 24 - CTIME.HOURS(bedtime-outofbed).
ELSE.
  COMPUTE sleepDur = CTIME.HOURS(outofbed-bedtime).
END IF.
EXECUTE.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Andy! Perfect solution. Now that I know it I kind of feel stupid I could not come up with it myself.